# Install Windows 10 on HDD on a laptop having Ubuntu already installed on SSD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, ssd, grub

I have recently purchased a new laptop and it came with Ubuntu preinstalled on a 128 GB SSD configured to boot via UEFI. I wish to dual boot the system and installed Windows on a partition on the HDD, but after installation there is no option to boot Windows. I suppose grub doesn't detect Windows on another drive. So, what do I have to do to make everything work?

Comment: If Ubuntu boots via UEFI, did you install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive. How you boot install media, is then how it installs. Post this above: `sudo parted -l` If sdb is MBR(msdos), not gpt then you installed in BIOS boot mode. UEFI systems cannot switch boot mode after start of boot. Or grub will only boot other installs in same boot mode. You may be able to directly boot from UEFI boot menu.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Endeed sdb is msdos. Actually at first when creating a USB with Windows installer I chose gpt. But it gave me an error, saying that I should choose msdos. So what do I have to do now? There is no option to boot Windows in UEFI either. I've tried to add it manually choosing file Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi but it also gives an error

Comment: I do not think it matters with installer flash drive is gpt or MBR. But how you boot install media does matter. If you have allow boot from USB in UEFI settings or external drives on, you should get two boot options one UEFI: and one without UEFI and just name or label of flash drive. External drives only boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which with Windows is a copy of Windows .efi boot file. In Ubuntu same file name is copy of grub/shimx64.efi to boot Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the following command in Linux will cause GRUB to detect Windows:

```
    sudo update-grub
```

Note that the Windows partition must be mounted in Linux for it to be detected.

Comment: I've already tried this, but didn't work for some reason. Maybe I did something wrong. I've typed following commands in terminal:

Comment: $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo os-prober
$ sudo update-grub
Создание конфигурационного файла grub...
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-1028-oem
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-1028-oem
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-1021-oem
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-1021-oem
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration

Comment: I don't understand the language, but if the standard methods don't work, you might try some GRUB-rescue product, for example [Super Grub Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).